# how to read file from a specific point make changes in the same file?C++

Tags: c++11

I have to read file contains whats given below.
Read the coordinates which come after the v's, multiply 1st with  user input x and second with y and third with z, for each line staring with v.
Have to write these changes in the same file.
can someone please help with c++

## OBJ file created by ply_to_obj.c

> ## g Object001
>
> v  -0.57735  -0.57735  0.57735 v  0.934172  0.356822  0 v  0.934172 
>   -0.356822  0 v  -0.934172  0.356822  0 v  -0.934172  -0.356822  0 v  0  0.934172  0.356822 v  0  0.934172  -0.356822 v  0.356822  0  -0.934172 v  -0.356822  0  -0.934172 v  0  -0.934172  -0.356822 v  0  -0.934172 
>   0.356822 v  0.356822  0  0.934172 v  -0.356822  0  0.934172 v  0.57735  0.57735  -0.57735 v  0.57735  0.57735  0.57735 v  -0.57735  0.57735  -0.57735 v  -0.57735  0.57735  0.57735 v  0.57735  -0.57735  -0.57735 v  0.57735  -0.57735  0.57735 v  -0.57735  -0.57735  -0.57735
>
> f  19  3  2 f  12  19  2 f  15  12  2 f  8  14  2 f  18  8  2 f  3  18
>   2 f  20  5  4 f  9  20  4 f  16  9  4 f  13  17  4 f  1  13  4 f  5  1
>   4 f  7  16  4 f  6  7  4 f  17  6  4 f  6  15  2 f  7  6  2 f  14  7 
>   2 f  10  18  3 f  11  10  3 f  19  11  3 f  11  1  5 f  10  11  5 f 
>   20  10  5 f  20  9  8 f  10  20  8 f  18  10  8 f  9  16  7 f  8  9  7
>   f  14  8  7 f  12  15  6 f  13  12  6 f  17  13  6 f  13  1  11 f  12 
>   13  11 f  19  12  11

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to read the file content and store it in a string container in C++. Maybe you can split the string based on v's

```
#include <stringstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    string ReadFromFile(string FilePath)
    {
        ifstream file(FilePath);
        string test;
        cout << "path: " << FilePath;
        try
        {
            std::stringstream buffer;
            buffer << file.rdbuf();
            test = buffer.str();
            cout << test;
            return test;
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            throw std::exception(e.what());
        }
    }

    std::vector<string> SplitStringIntoMultipleParameters(string input, string delimiter)
    {
    std::stringstream stringStream(input);
    std::string line;

    std::vector<string> TokenizedStringVector;

    while (std::getline(stringStream, line))
    {
        size_t prev = 0, pos;
        while ((pos = line.find_first_of(delimiter, prev)) != string::npos)
        {
            if (pos > prev)
                TokenizedStringVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, pos - prev));
            prev = pos + 1;
        }
        if (prev < line.length())
            TokenizedStringVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, string::npos));
    }
    return TokenizedStringVector;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 string FilePath;
 if(argc == 2)
 {
   FilePath = argv[1];
 }

  string TextReadFromFile = ReadFromFile(FilePath);
  std::vector<string> tokenizedString = SplitStringIntoMultipleParameters(TextReadFromFile, "v");

//Do required calculations by iterating over the vector of strings

return 0;
}
```